# AlphaServer 1000 4/266 in a new system Alpha Server 1000A 5/333 DU3.2C

Tags: kernel

I tried to boot the disks that had the operating system that initially
were on an AlphaServer 1000 4/266 in a new system Alpha Server 1000A
5/333.
And when I tried to boot the generic vmunix, it gave me the message:

> Warning: Proc-Type 7/sys-type 1b unknown
>   Processor type is not configured or not supported. If you are installing
>   a new version of the operating system please refer to the installation
>   guide or Hardware Upgrade rel. If you are booting a new kernel, check
>   the ´cpu´ keyword in the kernel configuration file. Refer to the system
>   Administration.
>
> Halting CPU0
>
> Halt code=5

Answer (score 0):

to overcome this you can copy these two files ( VMUNIX & GENVMUNIX) from another 
node (work station DEC alpha 1000A) they are placed at the root make sure that , it should be the same operating system (my problem) o.s. Unix ver 3.2c rev 148 
 thanks